# How to use scipy weave and sscanf to parse string to numpy array?

Tags: python, scipy, scanf

I'm working on some scientific python code which I would like to speed up. One specific problem is reading in lots data which is stored in text files using formated strings. I figured out that the approach using split() and np.array() works nicely, but is really slow if compared to what I'm used from FORTRAN.

I'm wondering weather scipy.weave could be used here, unfortunately I'm no expert in C. Here is an example:

```
line ="  0.7711408E-01  0.7616138E-01  0.7521919E-01"
arr = np.array(line.split(),dtype=np.float)
print arr
```

This works, but is far to slow for large data sets. What about something like this, bu working?

```
line ="  0.7711408E-01  0.7616138E-01  0.7521919E-01"
arr = np.zeros(3)
weave.inline("""sscanf(std::string(line).c_str(),"%f %f %f",arr);""",['line','arr'])
print arr
```

Comment: numpy.fromfile() should do what you say faster i think, but i would suggest you consider not saving stuff in .txt if you have loads of them, use something that saves stuff in binary since thats better for diskspace, and io too i guess (.fits i am currently thinking of, but other similar dataformats exist) (how many Gb are your files in size?)

Comment: I don't want to touch large parts of the program. The output (~10GB) is generated by a number of FORTRAN programs. I think for those, putting the data into formated text is the easiest thing. I was showing an easy to digest example. The real world case is more complicated an numpy.fromfile() won't work. The split() way, Python really spends to much time doing the same thing over and over aggin.

Comment: how many files is the output? and size of each file? (if it is like 10000+ files, than it is worth rewriting all your data into one big file, save it in .fits or so, so it takes far less diskspace, and than your IO will go much faster, though you have to go through the one time of writing the one big file)

Comment: Of course this is possible, I was hoping to find a nice way in python to deal with the problem. For me it seem weired to do the slow split() np.array() conversion if I can safely assume that the data is formated. There is no need to search for the delimiter all the time because i know where is it. There is no need to do all kind of test when doing the float conversion because  I know exactly how the string looks like. I just want to avoid all the overkill which is limiting my performance..., but thanks for your ideas anyway!

Comment: The thing that is limiting your performance is *10GB of text files*. :)  If modifying the Fortran code is an option, consider writing your data using the HDF5 format (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/; http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/fortran/).  Then use h5py or PyTables to read the data in python.

Comment: You might be right, but only in Python. With Fortran reading the gig's of text files is approx 100 times faster. Having that speed in python would be sufficient for me.